# Phonegap working with Android but not with iOS, Error Code

Tags: ios, cordova

I am getting this error code when i open a phonegap html site in iOS:

```
gap:["Device","getDeviceInfo","Device341875241"]
gap:["NetworkStatus","getConnectionInfo","NetworkStatus341875242"]
gap:["App","show","App341875243"]
```

It is working with Android perfectly.. i am using cordova 2.7.0.

What´s that supposed to mean?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the correct cordova-2.7.0.js file that is specific to iOS. This error usually occurs when you add cordova JS file which is not specific to a particular platform. In other words, **you should add the iOS specific cordova-2.7.0 JS file to your iOS PhoneGap project**.

Possible scenario:

You might have wrongly included the Android specific cordova-2.7.0 JS file in your iOS project.

Fix:

Just remove the current cordova JS file and add the cordova-2.7.0.js file from iOS folder in the downloaded Phonegap-2.7.0 folder

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, i will try this and accept your aswer if it works :)